# how to convert from integer number into decimal number in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-analysis

I'm creating a scatter plot and i need to convert an integer number into decimal number, so what i need to do?

**Here is my code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
day = pd.read_csv("day.csv")
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,8))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.scatterplot(x = "temp", y = "cnt", data = day, )
ax.scatter(x, y, marker = 'o')
ax.set_title("Bike Rentals at Different Temperatures" , fontsize = 14)
ax.set_xlabel("Count of Total Bike Rentals", fontsize = 12)
ax.set_ylabel("Normalized Temperature", fontsize = 12)
plt.show()
```

**This is what i got :**

[image]

**This is what i need to do:**
[image: This is what i need to do:]

Comment: Could you please give us a sample of your data?

Comment: What is your actual problem?  That code is for plotting some data, what does that have to do with converting integers to decimals?

Comment: Also , could you elaborate on what does "Normalized Temperatue" is? Also You set x-label to be `Count of Total Bike Rentals` and y-label to be `Normalized Temperature`, but in your desired graph, the x-label is `Normalized Temperature`... The data - x is `temp` and y is `cnt`...

Comment: I think all you need is to set min and max value for x-axis. All your observations (dots)] look scattered between 0 and 1. I guess there is outlier that brakes it for you (the orange dot).

Comment: my actual problem is changing numbers at the top of Normalized Temperature, for example: In my case there are integer numbers, but i need to convert them into decimal.

Comment: As already asked - show sample of your data. Also - look at your graph (the one you get now), all x values are between 0 and 1, except the orange dot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use type-casting :

```
n = 5
n = float(5)
```

Or in any programming language you can simply divide n by `1.0` to produce a floating point number:

```
n = 5
n = n / 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables in python are dynamically typed, which means the data type of a variable is determined at runtime. Because of this integers often will behave as floating point numbers when needed. Alternatively they can be converted using the float-function.

We can examine this behaviour using the isinstance method to determine the data type. Consider this example:

```
n = 2
m = 3
print(isinstance(n, int)) # True

a = n / m
print(isinstance(a, int)) # False
print(isinstance(a, float)) # True

b = n + 1.0
print(isinstance(b, int)) # False
print(isinstance(b, float)) # True
```

Division in python produces a float in python, regardless of whether the inputs are integers, floats or a combination of the two. To use floor division, a separate operator is used i.e. `n // m`, which always produces an integer.

Addition however will produce an integer if both number are integers, and output a float if either numbers is a float. In a similar fashion, conversion of integers to floats is handled by a lot of functions and libraries automatically.

Due to this behaviour, it should not be necessary to coerce the data type at most times. For an explicit conversion, you may use the built-in function float.

```
n = 2
print(isinstance(n, int)) # True

n = float(n)
print(isinstance(n, float)) # True
```